# Not able to set the color of top most area in html and it also remains uncolored from sides

Tags: html, css

I am writing this code in neatbeans,please help me with the correct solution as soon as possible.

Please see the attached image for more understanding of the problem.

code writing:-

IN HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign-In</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="body-color">

    <div id="heading">
        <p style="color: white">
            CONNECT-U
        </p>
    </div>

<div id="signin">
<fieldset style="width:30%"><legend>LOG-IN HERE</legend>
<form method="POST" action="connectivity.php">
User-ID <br><input type="text" name="user" size="40"><br>
Password <br><input type="password" name="pass" size="40">
<br>
<br>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In">
</div>
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

IN CSS:

```
#body-color{
background-color:#6699CC;
}
#heading{
    margin-top:0em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size:2em;

    background: #696969

}
#signin{
margin-top:207px;
margin-bottom:207px;
margin-right:434px;
margin-left:434px;
border:3px solid #a1a1a1;
padding:9px 35px; 
background:#f8f8ff;
opacity: 1.5;
width:400px;
border-radius:20px;
box-shadow: 7px 7px 6px;
}
#button{
border-radius:10px;
width:75px;
height:37px;
background:#6495ed;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:20px
}
```

[THE TOP MOST AREA IS OF COLOR AS THE BACKGROUND COLOR,I WANT IT TO BE LIKE THE COLOR OF BACKGROUND OF THE HEADING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FzNf.png)

Comment: #body-color{
background-color:#6699CC; padding:0px;
}

Comment: you remove the top margin from the paragraph in the heading,check answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

First add `margin: 0px;` to your `#body-color` like

```
#body-color{
    background-color:#6699CC;
    margin: 0px;
 }
```

Then remove the top margin in your paragraph which is in the `#heading` div

```
<p style="color: white;margin-top:0px">
        CONNECT-U
    </p>
```